# Writing a display function in another file than main

Tags: python

I would like to write a function that displays any text given in argument with a specific color if wanted, but when i call it with whatever string it only returns :

```
<generator object color_display.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x10aad59e0>
```

Here is the code of my function (I use colorama.Fore to color my text):

```
def color_display(*args, color=Fore.WHITE)
     print(color)
     print(txt for txt in args)
     print(Fore.RESET)
```

How can i fix this ? :,(

Comment: that isn't python2, it's python 3

Answer (score 0):

The notation `txt for txt in args` is a generator, an iterable that can be iterated on

You just want something like

```
print(*args)  # print all separator by space

print(",".join(args))  # separator by comma

print(args)  # as a tuple : (1, 3, "jj")

print(list(args))  # as a list : [1, 3, "jj"]
```